# Convert html/css file to pdf file

Tags: html, css, computer-vision

I just designed CV with html/css. Is there a way to convert my CV to pdf ?
Or can you recommend me to write a CV by any tool?
please help me !

Comment: Don't understand how this can be related to this programming site. Do you have a code to share?

Comment: I am loving the computer vision tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just your CV, try something like printscreen or a tool like [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/) instead. It's quite hard to go neatly from html/css to pdf. You'll notice when you try ctrl+P that the content is not in the right place. An image to pdf is easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the page(Your CV) in browser
2. Hit Ctrl + P(Print the page)
3. Select PDF as option while saving